Is this sequence "ALTER ..." an attack of some kind?
The seqence below is a form submission on a personal site of mine and seems to be crashing the browser.
It crashes the browser tab (becomes unresponsive) of my site's backend where I approve submissions, and it crashes gmail when displaying the email notification of the submission. At least I think it's this submission...
I'm wondering if it's some kind of attack that takes advantage of some memory vulnerability or something... like a memory overflow. I don't know... I'm not an expert.
The sequence doesn't look malicious, but it (I think it) has crashed my mail and browser several times today.
Took me a minute to track it down because it was just gmail dying (javascript busy / timeout). I traced it back to when that message was loaded on screen.
I then hunted it down in my app. I tried to look online but didn't come up with much.
Any help appreciated, and especially how to guard against this. I'm a web developer, but this isn't an attack I recognize. It seems to have an effect even when escaped.
Thanks
Update: once I added the sequence in a comment below, this tab became unresponsive (and only this tab), so I have to edit this in Safari. I'll disable plugins tomorrow and see what that does... Very strange.



This is probably what’s called a regex DoS (ReDoS) attack.

I originally didn't post the sequence because I didn't want to cause the issue, but now I'm curious: ALTER 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000⁰000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I'm confused about the question. What "seems to be crashing the browser. .. crashed my mail and browser" really means - crash of browser, slowdown/crash of specific site only, ... ? Also what has  " gmail dying" to do with this - how exatly the data end up in gmail and do they have proper encoding for mail? I think that question needs more details on what is actually happening and how things work together (your site, external post, gmail, ...) instead of only giving selected information. For now one can only speculate  - and ReDoS is just a wild but not totally unfounded speculation.

@Ja1024 well, as Steffen Ullrich says, it’s probably very unlikely but the most feasible option assuming what the OP says is true. But I personally think they are getting a bit confused- do you know of anything that can crash Gmail with a notification(!)? I sure don’t. Crashing a browser is different, but the whole situation seems very implausible. What do you think?

OP, please consider blurring out details in screenshots such as people’s IP addresses. This can, dependant on the state, count as PII, and can be illegal to distribute.

The comment above causes my chrome browser with the 00000... to freeze

Yes, this looks entirely more like a technical issue rather than a security one. A glitch, not a vulnerability. Maybe both, though.

It may be an issue with one of the plugins. I can look into that tomorrow.

Then this issue is entirely your browser's problem. This doesn't happen for me or any other stack exchange user for that matter.

"Alter" is a perfectly cromulent word in several languages, and used regularly both for text and data. Just having it outside of any command context is no problem for contemporary browsers or mail applications.

My gut says it's not about the "ALTER" string, but maybe the following bit. Even if it's an issue with one of my extensions or combination, it's still malicious on some level since it caused the tabs containing it to hang. Even if it's just causing some regex to consume lots of resources or something similar... Just curious what this is about and thought folks here might have an idea. It's clearly not nothing, but perhaps not something the actual browser is vulnerable to. Thanks for the input. Still curious what the actual vector is and how to prevent it in the future.

@pixelearth again, this is your browser’s local issue, and only your browser’s. What browser do you use? I recommend updating it. What OS do you use?

You’re probably on the right track with browser extensions.
